# gitignore file does not ignores and git rm actually removes the files

Tags: git, github, yii

So I was finding a solution wherein .gitignore should ignore the files I tell it to. But turns out if you have already committed them, .gitignore file doesn't matter. The suggested solution is git rm filename.
My problem is,
There is a repo I want to contribute to, which had already committed all the initial files. So I added few file names which I want to gitignore in .gitignore and committed it pushed it and pull request was merged.
Now I'm making changes to one of the gitignore files, when I do git status it says modifies(expected). So I do a git rm index.php and the file is deleted. This should not be the solution, right? So should I delete it commit it and push pull it? It would be gone then.
I am sure I am doing something wrong.
Any help welcomed.
P.S. I read this [Git Ready Link](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html) but doing assume unchanged everytime, is not feasible.

My gitignore file looks something like this:

```
/index.php
/assets/*
/protected/config/*
/protected/runtime/*
*~
[#]*[#]
```

Comment: Did you check in your .gitignore file?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you want to ignore a file that has already been committed? Maybe [`git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html) is what you are after?

Comment: because config files are different for every machine. and if you are familiar with yii framework, you'll know why to ignore runtime and assets. It's just not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged config_file
```

instead of modifying `.gitignore` file to ignore them.

By this way, you can keep files there but any changes made will be ignored. When you need to modify it, use

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged config_file
```

to re-track the file. Then you can commit the modification on `config_file`.

I think this is a better way to manage configuration related files. `.gitignore` is better for temporally files. :)

Comment: So till the time I dont want it to track changes it'll just be there? I mean i'll keep pushiny code everytime without explicitly writing it. I just need to do it once right?

Comment: and moreover, the line you mentioned is already suggested in the link git ready, that looks bad because I have folders that I need to ignore.

Comment: @dibs_ab it's better to modify one by one, otherwise, when you modified one, others will be submit either

Comment: @dibs_ab i.e., you can use the command I said for all files under `/protected/config/` (like `/protected/config/config_file_one`, ...), and keep `/assets/*` & `/protected/runtime/*` in `.gitignore` cause files there are generated in runtime as you said.

Comment: dint get you Kjuly. these files are configuration files. Evrytime I commit, its gonna be changed. I need a permanent solution.

Comment: @dibs_ab you can keep a copy of your own configuration files, but the lines for basic configuration format like `SERVER_HOST: XXX` can be kept there. So others can get this config file & modify it to fit there own need. You can take a look at mine: https://github.com/Kjuly/iPokeMon/blob/dev/Pokemon/Config.m